# What is the difference between "periodic" and "cron" on OS X?

Tags: macos, scheduled-tasks, cron

1. I bought a book on OS X and it says that **launchd** now control the scheduling of cron tasks, it this true?
2. Also it says that if I place commands in `/etc/daily.local` that they will execute after the scripts in `/etc/periodic/daily`.

   In my `/etc/daily.local` script, I just have a simple `touch` command (which just creates a file) so I can test to see if it works.

   I manually ran

   ```
   sudo /usr/sbin/periodic daily
   ```

   to force it to execute. The file was never created.
3. Where did I got wrong, or misunderstand anything?  How should I be scheduling cron jobs in OSX Lion? Why did my book tell me to do it this way?

**I'm starting to think `periodic` is different from `cron`. What is `/usr/sbin/periodic`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files under /etc/periodic are indeed a different system than cron and crontabs.  I don't advise messing with it.  Use a root crontab entry instead.  Run `sudo crontab -e` and add these lines:

```
MAILTO=me@foo.com
0 0 * * * sh /path/to/your/script
```

The first line tells cron to mail any output from the script to me@foo.com; change me@foo.com to your email address.

The second line tells cron to run your script every day at midnight.

Comment: If I run crontab -e under my login will it run the script as me (vs. running at root with sudo)? Does it run the script as root with sudo? Also in what file does it add this line to?

Comment: Yes, using `crontab -e` without sudo will create a personal crontab, and the jobs defined in it will run as you.  Using `sudo crontab -e` creates a root crontab, and anything in it gets run as root (not with sudo, but the result is the same).  The actual crontab files are created as /usr/lib/cron/tabs/<username>.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. I bought a book on OS X and it says that **launchd** now control the scheduling of cron tasks, it this true?

Yes, It's true, According to the [Scheduling Timed Jobs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-CH1-SW1) in the Daemons and Services Programming Guide. The `periodic` jobs are deprecated and using `launchd` is the preferred way to management scheduling tasks rather than `cron`.

In fact, Both `periodic` and `cron` are managed by the `launchd`, As you can see below or described in manpages of `periodic(8)` and `cron(8)`.

```
$ sudo launchctl list | grep 'periodic\|cron'
6706    0       com.apple.systemstats.microstackshot_periodic
-       0       com.apple.periodic-monthly
-       0       com.apple.periodic-weekly
21057   0       com.apple.periodic-daily
-       0       com.vix.cron

$ cat com.vix.cron.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
        "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.vix.cron</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/usr/sbin/cron</string>
        </array>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <dict>
                <key>PathState</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>/etc/crontab</key>
                        <true/>
                </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>QueueDirectories</key>
        <array>
                <string>/usr/lib/cron/tabs</string>
        </array>
        <key>EnableTransactions</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

> 2. Also it says that if I place commands in /etc/daily.local that they will execute after the scripts in /etc/periodic/daily.
>
> In my /etc/daily.local script, I just have a simple touch command (which just creates a file) so I can test to see if it works.
>
> I manually ran
>
> sudo /usr/sbin/periodic daily 
>   to force it to execute. The file was never created.

I tested it and it works on my machine which is macOS Catalina.
The `/etc/daily.local` file is defined in `/etc/defaults/periodic.conf` file and get executed by `/etc/periodic/daily/999.local` script. So make sure you have both files there.

```
$ cat /etc/periodic/daily/999.local
#!/bin/sh
#
# $FreeBSD: src/etc/periodic/daily/999.local,v 1.5 2001/06/01 16:40:55 dougb Exp $
#
# Run the old /etc/daily.local script.  This is really for backwards
# compatibility more than anything else.
#

# If there is a global system configuration file, suck it in.
#
if [ -r /etc/defaults/periodic.conf ]
then
    . /etc/defaults/periodic.conf
    source_periodic_confs
fi

rc=0
for script in $daily_local
do
    echo ''
    case "$script" in
        /*)
            if [ -f "$script" ]
            then
                echo "Running $script:"

                sh $script || rc=3
            else
                echo "$script: No such file"
                [ $rc -lt 2 ] && rc=2
            fi;;
        *)
            echo "$script: Not an absolute path"
            [ $rc -lt 2 ] && rc=2;;
    esac
done

exit $rc
```

> 3. Where did I got wrong, or misunderstand anything?  How should I be scheduling cron jobs in OSX Lion? Why did my book tell me to do it this way?

Althrough it had good and short answer on 
 https://superuser.com/a/391214/106136 by @kyle-jones, I am going to give the example in the `launchd` way here, Check it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ) for more details.

The following property list runs the program `happybirthday` at midnight every time July 11 falls on a Sunday, Save it as 'foo.plist' and run it with command `launchctl load /path/to/plist`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.happybirthday</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>happybirthday</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Day</key>
        <integer>11</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Month</key>
        <integer>7</integer>
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

> **I'm starting to think `periodic` is different from `cron`. What is `/usr/sbin/periodic`?**

The `periodic` is a utility that written in shell script, which organized scripts in separated folders named `daily`, `weekly` and `monthly`, and is intended to be called by `launchd(8)` to execute shell scripts located in the specified directory at the right time.

```
$ file `which periodic`
/usr/sbin/periodic: POSIX shell script text executable, ASCII text
$ tree -Ca /etc/periodic/
/etc/periodic/
|-- daily
|   |-- 110.clean-tmps
|   |-- 130.clean-msgs
|   |-- 140.clean-rwho
|   |-- 199.clean-fax
|   |-- 310.accounting
|   |-- 400.status-disks
|   |-- 420.status-network
|   |-- 430.status-rwho
|   `-- 999.local
|-- monthly
|   |-- 199.rotate-fax
|   |-- 200.accounting
|   `-- 999.local
`-- weekly
    `-- 999.local
```